# Using a React hook in separate file to the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am wanting to create a data file for my project instead of having everything in the one file, however I am using React hooks to load in images. This becomes a problem when I want to have everything in separate files. The code gives me the 'Invalid hook call' message which I understand why it is wrong, but can't figure out how to get it to work for me.

**EventData.js**

```
import React from "react"
import Image from "gatsby-image"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"

const getImages = graphql`
  {
    btu: file(relativePath: { eq: "eventImage/btu.jpeg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fixed(height: 120, width: 500) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed_withWebp_tracedSVG
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const data = useStaticQuery(getImages)
export const details = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: <Image fixed={data.btu.childImageSharp.fixed} />,
    date: "2 Oct 2020",
    distance: "30km - 160km",
    name: "Brisbane Trail Ultra",
    location: "Brisbane, QLD",
  },
]
```

**EventCalendar.js**

```
const EventCalendar = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <section>
        {details.map(details => {
          return <EventCard key={details.id} {...details}></EventCard>
        })}
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Comment: The only ground rule here is hooks should be invoked from within the component. Here you are triggering it from outside, which won't work. It's not necessary that you put everything in the same file, but you need to achieve this with component (and function) breakdown and you could move the broken components and functions to separate files.

Comment: Been messing around with my code based on your suggestions, and I am just not getting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a custom hook, which looks something like this in your case:

```
import React from "react"
import Image from "gatsby-image"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"

const getImages = graphql`
  {
    btu: file(relativePath: { eq: "eventImage/btu.jpeg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fixed(height: 120, width: 500) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed_withWebp_tracedSVG
        }
      }
    }
  }
  `;

export function useDetails() {    
  const data = useStaticQuery(getImages);

  return [
    {
      id: 1,
      img: <Image fixed={data.btu.childImageSharp.fixed} />,
      date: "2 Oct 2020",
      distance: "30km - 160km",
      name: "Brisbane Trail Ultra",
      location: "Brisbane, QLD",
    },
  ];
}
```

To define custom hooks, define a function, which returns your desired values. In this function you can all hooks available from the react API.

Then in your main file write

```
const EventCalendar = () => {
  const details = useDetails();

  return (
    <Layout>
      <section>
        {details.map(detail => {
          return <EventCard key={details.id} {...detail}></EventCard>
        })}
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am trying to actually import the graphql file.

That would be great. I am getting an error on the gatsby graphql loader.

Answer (score 0):

Only Call Hooks from React Functions
Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:

✅ Call Hooks from React function components.

✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).
Another thing:
Inside the map, you should change details to detail because is an item

```
const EventCalendar = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <section>
        {details.map(detail => {
          return <EventCard key={details.id} {...detail}></EventCard>
        })}
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

You can read about hook is here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

My suggestion is you can wrap it into component like that:

```
const ImageHook = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(getImages)
  return <Image fixed={data.btu.childImageSharp.fixed}/>
}

export const details = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img:  <ImageHook />,
    date: "2 Oct 2020",
    distance: "30km - 160km",
    name: "Brisbane Trail Ultra",
    location: "Brisbane, QLD",
  },
]
```

Comment: I know how react hooks work. I am asking if there is anyway I can get it to work in the 'data.js' file.

Comment: what if I have multiple images in my query then? I simplified my code, but my actual code loads 3 different images